# Time slice function without a OS scheduler

Tags: c, embedded

I have a part of a library that processes data and takes quite a long time. In some cases it's not possible to wait for the results of the function but there are other tasks that should be done. On a system with an OS that's not a problem, as the scheduler can help with that.
But there are also systems that have no OS available. On these systems I want to achieve something similiar, i.e. the function is called does some calculations and returns after a given period (say 10ms). Then the other things are done and the data processing function gets called again and takes off at the position it left.

```
while(1) {
    process_data(); // resumes from where it returned before, runs for 10ms and returns
    do_other_stuff();
    and_some_more_stuff();
}
```

How can this be achieved?

I already found the concept of protothreads, but this would mean that I have to add stuff like PT_WAIT after every x statements that might take 10ms to compute. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have any "spare" interrupt which you can trigger in your code (i.e., not an interrupt triggered from an external controller), then you can "hook" on that. For example, divide-by-zero (though watch out for this specific example, because you will lose the ability to catch such bug later in the development of your SW). Otherwise, define time slots, split your infinite loop into these slots, and perform the desired operation at each slot.

Comment: Protothreads don't magically create suspendable functions, you still need to modify your functions to jump out of the loop all the time (although the inner workings are hidden inside C macros). So if you're going to do this, why not simply modify your function to work in small chunks? Alternatively, do the processing inside a low level interrupt (e.g. your main function), and use higher priority interrupts to break execution and do "more important stuff" in regular intervals.

Comment: What people normally do when faced with your problem is they add/create a small task scheduler(could be as simple as [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TimerScheduler)), so you can in fact have multiple tasks running. Or they run small functions (like your `do_other_stuff()/and_some_more_stuff()` within e.g. a timer interrupt, or they rewrite your `process_data()` function, so it is not long running, but processes just a small piece of data, remembers how far it has come, and resumes processing where it left off next time it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `process_data` function as a state machine.  Divide the too-long processing algorithm into multiple shorter steps/states.  Declare a static state variable within `process_data` so that it remembers its previous state each invocation.  Each time `process_data` is called it performs only one state.  Then when it's called again it picks up where it left off and performs the next step.  With this method the amount of time each invocation takes will be determined by how you divide the steps at design time.  You won't be able to limit the execution time at run time.

If the processing is something that is performed in a repetitive loop then perhaps you can read a hardware timer in the loop and break out of the loop when the time limit is reached.  But use static variables to remember on the next invocation where the processing left off.

Answer (score 2):

As long as `other_stuff` is reasonably short, you can do it in a timer ISR.

In case you don't want to use the task context savings of an (RT)OS, you have to implement them on your own - break your long-running processing function down into pieces, save the processing context and return to your main dispatching point. After the next step is done, come back to the saved context and re-start processing where you left off. (This is more or less what protothreads do)

The end consequence is that once you're done, you might have implemented most of the parts of a multitasking time-slicing OS.